# Add CSS code only to pages generated by WP Plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web

I was given the task of customizing a specific section of a website. This section is primarily made by an Event Manager Plugin on WordPress. This plugin allows users to create their own events that will be published in a calendar page. The thing is, I need to get rid of the page header only on the pages created by this plugin, that will have an URL similar to this: http://mypage.com/eventos/user-event-name

So, I only need to apply the code `.site-header { display: none; }` ONLY to the pages that have this /eventos/something URL. Can this be done?
When I put the above code on the Custom CSS of my theme it gets rid of the header across the whole website, and I don't want that.

I have absolutely no background in CSS so I most definitely am using the wrong definitions here. Thanks in advance, hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is evestos in URL and add a class to body
like this

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

    $url = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if($url, "/eventos/")) {     
        $classes[] = 'eventos-page';         
    return $classes;          
    }
}
```

After that you can add css to that class like for example

```
.eventos-page .site-header { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Hello Boris! That sounds like a great solution! Now my question is: Where would I need to put that code? I'm guessing a .php file but which one? I'm sorry, I'm really new to all this so I don't really know.

Comment: The upper one in functions.php
The lower in styles.css